# Can I select row where not in RIGHT JOIN or JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, right-join

I want to find groups which doesn't participate at an event.

There is my table:

groupe :

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| id_groupe | id_createur |    name   | description |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|     1     |      5      |   tagada  |    epic     |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------+
|     2     |      1      |   banana  |    good     |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|     3     |      1      | blueberry |  legendary  |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|     4     |      2      |   coco    |    great    |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

The group 1 was create by member 5, his name is 'tagada' and his description is 'epic'.

event :

```
+-----+-------------+----------------+
| id  |     name    |  description   | 
+-----+-------------+----------------+
|  1  |    lunch    |for lunch monday|
+-----+-------------+----------------+
|  2  |    game     | play videogame |
+-----+-------------+----------------+
```

The name of the event 1 is "lunch" and his decription is "for lunch monday".

groupe_events :

```
+--------------+--------------+
| id_groupe_ge | id_events_ge |
+--------------+--------------+
|      1       |      2       |
+--------------+--------------+
|      2       |      2       |
+--------------+--------------+
|      3       |      2       |
+--------------+--------------+
|      1       |      1       |
+--------------+--------------+
|      3       |      1       |
+--------------+--------------+
```

For example, groupe 1, 2 and 3 will participate to the events 2 AND groupe 1 and 4 will participate to the events 1

If I use LEFT JOIN, I can't specified the id of the event (id_groupe_ge)

Mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM groupe 
    LEFT JOIN groupe_events ON id_groupe_ge = id_groupe 
WHERE id_groupe_ge IS NULL
```

OR
Mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM groupe 
    LEFT JOIN groupe_events ON id_groupe_ge = id_groupe 
WHERE id_events_ge IS NULL OR id_events_ge <> 2
```

With this method, i have also the rows of the id_events_ge 1

If I use classique JOIN and WHERE, I have groups which participate and this exactly the opposite

Mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM groupe 
    JOIN groupe_events ON id_groupe_ge = id_groupe 
WHERE id_events_ge = 2
```

How can I find groups which doesn't participate at the event 2 for example?
Here this one :

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|     4     |      2      |   coco    |    great    |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Other example, i want find groups which doesn't participate at the event 1 for example?
Here this one :

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|     2     |      1      |   banana  |    good     |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
|     4     |      2      |   coco    |    great    |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: You want to get all group who are not participating in any of the events or you will always have an event id for which you want to fetch group that are not participating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the groups that don't participate in a *specific* event, you need to include that condition in your `JOIN`, and then check for a resultant `NULL` value in the `groupe_events` table. For example, to find groups not participating in event 1:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM groupe g
LEFT JOIN groupe_events ge ON ge.id_groupe_ge = g.id_groupe AND ge.id_events_ge = 1
WHERE ge.id_groupe_ge IS NULL
```

Output:

```
id_groupe   id_createur name    description
2           1           banana  good
4           2           coco    great
```

And for event 2:

```
SELECT g.*
FROM groupe g
LEFT JOIN groupe_events ge ON ge.id_groupe_ge = g.id_groupe AND ge.id_events_ge = 2
WHERE ge.id_groupe_ge IS NULL
```

Output:

```
id_groupe   id_createur name    description
4           2           coco    great
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vHRSRyWPPQTYxCxUsFmcrQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Top answer your question:

> I want to find groups which doesn't participate at an event...

I would do an outer join, as in:

```
select g.*
from groupe g
left join groupe_events ge on ge.id_group_ge = g.id_groupe
where ge.id_group_ge is null
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find non-participating groups against a group-id then:

```
select group.*
from groupe
left join groupe_events on groupe_events.id_group_ge = groupe.id_groupe
where groupe_events.id_group_ge is null and groupe_events.id_events_ge = 'put-your-id-here'
```

Otherwise, use the same query as answered by @The Impaler